# Oaxaca decomposition for OLS regression - Is my calculation correct?

Tags: excel, decomposition

I am trying to decompose the gender pay gap with the Blinder-Oaxaca decomposition for OLS regression (two-fold) using: Stata, R, and manual calculation with Excel.

All programs give me similar results; however, I believe the results are wrong. The reason is, the slope for occupation varies a lot between the female and male regressions however, it explains -0.001% of the Overall Difference. I have been using deviation coding for a 4 level factor. And also tried to simplify the variable to only 2 levels ([0]Manager; [1]Other). (Using 1 and 2 for values does not help).

My calculatation:
(*β*:slope; *X*:mean for particular variable) I'm using log wages

```
             *βm     βf      Xm      Xf*

Occupation 0.031    0.183   0.14    0.14 

Explained occupation: βm(Xm-Xf)
Unexplained occupation: (βm-βf)Xf
```

So obviously the problem is I am multiplying 0.031 with (0.14-0.14) which equals to 0.

So my question is: Am I handling the factor variable correctly? What sense does it make to use the mean for a dummy (or deviation coded) factor variable?

However, as stated before; Oaxaca package for Stata gives me the same result as R and Excel (manual calc). I am lost.

Comment: This sounds like more of a stats question than an Excel question.  Try 'Cross Validated': http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, yes. I submitted to stackoverflow by mistake. Already flagged the question for transfer.